# How to insert BSONObj into another BSONObj in C++ (Mongo)

Tags: c++, mongodb, bson

I need something like this:

```
{
    "Field1" : "Value1",
    "Field2" : "Value2",
    "Fields3": [
              { "Field311" : Value311, "Field312" : Value312},
              { "Field321" : Value321, "Field322" : Value322},
              { "Field331" : Value323, "Field333" : [
                              ... some more fields here
              ]}
     ]
}
```

I get Fields1-2 from json string and convert them to mongo::BSONObj.
Then I add Field3 to root like this:

```
mongo::BSONArray arr;
root["Field3"].Obj=arr;
```

After that I want to fill Field3 in cycle, but I can't understand how to properly add BSONObj to array. I found "Add" method in [C# driver](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.3/html/f0360c8e-1672-316c-d92e-d80cb7bf9de6.htm), but there is no such thing for C++.
Google advices me to use ArrayBuilder, but I can't understand how.
Please, tell me, what should I do? Some examples would be very useful.

Also, a question: why there are BSONObj and BSONElement, some builders, etc...? Everything seems to be very complex after super simple JsonCpp (where everything is done by simply using [] and = operators and append() method).

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of using BSONArrayBuilder can be found here:
http://www.mongodb.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=19562815

And the corresponding documentation can be found here:
http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_b_s_o_n_array_builder.html

JsonCpp is an independently developed library and so there are many differences between how it works and how MongoDB's BSON implementation work -- for better or for worse. The BSON library is used extensively all throughout MongoDB and so its requirements are quite different from the JsonCpp requirements.

Hope this helps!